# Keep text consistent when inside Page View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitextview, uipageviewcontroller

I followed this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/ to embed a Page View Controller into another view using the Storyboard.

I modified it to show paragraphs of text, instead of images and simple labels. It all works fine, but as I change pages, the text does this annoying thing were it loads something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit er elit lamet, 
consectetaur
cillium adipisicing 
pecu.
```

Then, after a microsecond, it re-arranges itself to:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
er elit lamet, 
consectetaur cillium 
adipisicing pecu.
```

I've tried using a multi-line Label, and a Text View, and they both do this thing.

I suspect that it has to do with auto-layout, and that the text view is loading to the content view constraints, and then the content view adjusts to the parent's view.

Is there a way to make all that adjusting happen ahead of time?

Comment: I have the same issue with my TextView embedded within a PageViewController. My text is being loaded programmatically and is rearranging a split second after the view is presented.

Comment: @Trent I think it has to do with the "constrain to margins" option in the storyboard. I unchecked the margins from both views, and it solved the issue.